# TinyMCE: How to disable code rewriting?

Tags: text, joomla, tinymce, filtering

I'm trying to prevent TinyMCE (in Joomla) from rewriting code (adding, removing, moving tags and attributes, etc).  I don't want to setup every tag, just simply stop TinyMCE from changing my code.

The TinyMCE configuration:

```
verify_html:false;
```

doesn't work for me and toggling to the source code view or clicking show/hide still causes the editor to modify my source code.

Answer (score 2):

Go into the configuration of the tinyMCE plugin in Joomla and disable the code cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

Go to: extensions (Should be on the top tab control)

Click: Plug-in Manager

This will take you to a list of all of Joomla's plugins...
Disable any plugins that start with "-editor"

This should leave you with a bare bones editor which edits and saves basic text for Html without regard for what's in it. It's not pretty but if you found half as many bugs in Joomla's editor as I did, you'll be glad of the change.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to Hackwars answer: There is a file called `tinymce.php` holding the tinymce configuration. In this file you can change all necessary settings.

To disable the cleanup functionality you need to set

```
cleanup: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

**Joomla 2.5 (and 3.0) Solution:**

Login to your administration and go to `Site` > `Global Configuration` > `Text Filters`.

You can see that any input will have some joomla-side filters (regardless of what editor you use).

At that place you can easily change text filtering for any User Group.

Now Change **`Default Blacklist`** to **`No filtering`** for `Super Users` group.

More info at http://docs.joomla.org/Help30:Site_Global_Configuration#Text_Filters